# Iterable without element at index in Guava

Tags: java, guava

If I have a `FluentIterable`, how do I get a new `FluentIterable` without the element at index `i`?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built in for this, and no particularly great implementation either.

I'd honestly recommend using a mutable list and calling `remove(int index)`.  Fluent view chains really don't seem likely to be effective for this sort of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without mutable lists:

```
FluentIterable.concat(myIterable.limit(i), myIterable.skip(i + 1));
```

And here's a slightly more performant way:

```
ImmutableList<String> list = ImmutableList.copyOf(myIterable);
FluentIterable.concat(
    list.subList(0, i - 1),
    list.subList(i + 1, list.size() - 1));
```

Note that `#subList` is backed by the original `ImmutableList`, so we only iterate through `myIterable` once here.

Comment: Note you _can,_ but it's not going to be very efficient, especially if you do this more than once.

Comment: Correct, it will go through the iterable twice instead of once. I wonder if there's a built-in filter function that gives the value and the index as a pair. Then you could filter by index.

Comment: you might be able to pull it off with streams with `Streams.mapWithIndex`, but if you need things like this you're _really_ going to be better off with something mutable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I found another way that only iterates through once

Comment: Yes, that solution occurred to me as well.  Even so, something mutable is likely to perform better and be more readable.

Comment: I think it depends on the use. If you're applying more functional methods to the iterable like `filter` or `anyMatch`, then it's nice to keep everything in the immutable, functional style. I can see going in other directions for other uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying a transform to associate each element with its index, then filter out the element with the index you don't want, and finally transform each element with its index back to just the element. e.g.:

```
fluentIterable
        .transform(new WithIndexTransformer<>())
        .filter(indexedValue -> indexedValue.getIndex() != i)
        .transform(IndexedValue::getValue);
```

**IndexedValue.java**

```
public class IndexedValue<T> {
    private final int index;
    private final T value;

    IndexedValue(int index, T value) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**WithIndexTransformer.java**

```
public class WithIndexTransformer<T> implements Function<T, IndexedValue<T>> {
    private int index = 0;

    @Override
    public IndexedValue<T> apply(T input) {
        return new IndexedValue<>(index++, input);
    }
}
```